# How to iterate an array before responding to user using async

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I have a the following code that currently works
but... 
I know it is not elegant and can be done much more efficiently.

What I am trying to do is take an array of emails, search if they exist in a corresponding db with a particular templateName, and for those that do *not* exist (i.e are 'new'), list them back on the returned page to the user.  However, they end up waiting quite a while if there are a lot of emails to check.

This is the first time I'm using async and it may not actually be the best way to do this. Some of the below has been modified from what I am actually using currently to make it easier to read/follow.

Basically, from my handler, I call the following (where both emailArray and templateName are extracted from the request parameter passed in).

```
var newEmails = "";
async.eachSeries(emailArray, function(entry, cb) { // check each item in array (these are the potential new emails)
    utils.emailAddressAndTemplateExists(entry.toString().toLowerCase(), templateName, function (err, emailExists, templateExists ) {
      if (emailExists) {
        if (templateExists) {
          ++existingCount;
      } else if (emailExists && !templateExists) {
        } else {
          console.log('template does not exist');
        }
      } else {
        ++newCount;
        newEmails = newEmails + entry + "</br>";
      }
    cb();
    });
    //cb();
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
  var content = utils.getHTMLHead() + newEmails + utils.getHTMLClose();
  utils.writeHTMLPage(response, content); 
  });
```

The utils call does the following: (the writeHTMLPage simply adds the required html tags and sends back to response).

```
//checks for a single email address
var emailAddressExists = function(emailAddress, callback) {
    if (emailAddressCollection == null) {
      //console.log("it was null " + db_singleton + " " + dbName);
      emailAddressCollection = db_singleton.collection(dbName);
    }
    emailAddressCollection.find( { "emailAddress" : emailAddress.toLowerCase() } ).toArray( function (err, docs) {
      if (err) { console.err(err); }
      if (docs.length == 0) {
        callback(null, false, docs.EmailsSent);         
      } else {
        doc = docs[0];
        callback(null, true, doc.EmailsSent);
      } 
    });
} 
// check for email And template
var emailAddressAndTemplateExists = function (emailAddress, templateName, callback) {
  emailAddressExists(emailAddress, function (err, returnVal, templates) {
    if (returnVal) {
      if (templates != null) {
        callback (null, true, templates.hasOwnProperty(templateName)) // email exists, checking for templateName
      } else {
        callback (null, true, false); // email exists, no templates at all exist
      }
    } else {
      callback (null, false, false); // email does not exist, templates must be false
    }
  });
}

//creates HTML formated respnse data
function writeHTMLPage(response, content) {
 // if (err) { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write(content);
  response.end();
}
```

What are more elegant and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's constructed according to how you'd normally see it.  You can look into Promises with ES6 to get a better program flow:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Basically, it lets you chain together functions.  It's not too bad for what you're doing now, it might help out some, but if you have 4-5 callbacks nested together, that's when promises can be very helpful.

You'll just have to work through structuring your code differently to use Promises, but it'll make "callback hell" less of an issue.